# How to fix 404 page not found error in a website made in ghost?

Tags: ghost-blog

I have made a website in ghost. Other pages are working fine. The homepage was also working fine. But now it is showing 404 Page not found error. I tried googling but could not fix it.

The 404 error appeared earlier also. But it got fixed when I changed the theme. But now the 404 error is not getting fixed by changing the theme.

Can anyone help me how to fix it? This is the website url - `http://167.71.235.95/`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after creating a new page named Home.